# Passing non-initialised variable to function with array as argument

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization

Fairly new to C++. 
I have these declarations in the beginning of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int m, n;
void indtastVektor(double A[m]);
void indtastMatrix(double A[m][n]);
```

My main looks like this:

```
int main() {
    string svar;
    do {
        cout
                << "Ønskes indtastning af en vektor eller en matrix? Tast v for vektor og m for matrix: ";
        svar = cin;
        if (svar == "v" or svar == "V") {
            cout << "Indtast det ønskede antal rækker i vektoren som heltal: ";
            cin >> m;
            double vektor[m];
            indtastVektor(vektor);
            break;
        } else if (svar == "m" or svar == "M") {
            cout << "Indtast det ønskede antal rækker i matricen som heltal: ";
            cin >> m;
            cout << "Indtast det ønskede antal søjler i matricen som heltal: ";
            cin >> n;
            double matrix[m][n];
            indtastMatrix(matrix); // This line of code gives me an error
            break;
        } else {
            cout << "Intet gyldigt svar indtastet - forsøg igen. \n";
        }
    } while (true);
    return 0;
}
```

The line : indtastMatrix(matrix);  gives me the following error:

**no matching function for call to 'indtastMatrix'**

Basically the function takes a user-specified m and n and creates a two dimensional array with these values. Eclipse gives me this explanation:

**no known conversion from 'double [m][n]' to 'double (*)[n]' for 1st argument
void indtastMatrix(double A[m][n]);**

What exactly does this mean? I assume I might also need to initialise m and n before the main function?

The thing that makes me confused is the fact that this code doesn't return any errors:

```
cin >> m;
double vektor[m];
indtastVektor(vektor);
```

**How come I can initialise the variable at runtime and pass it to the function if the function takes a one-dimensional array as argument, but not if it's two dimensional?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using variable lengh array (VLA) which is a non standard extension.

Use `std::vector` instead. something like

```
void indtastVektor(std::vector<double>& v);
void indtastMatrix(std::vector<std::vector<double>>& v);

// ...

std::vector<double> vektor(m);
indtastVektor(vektor);

//...

std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix(m, std::vector<double>(n));
indtastMatrix(matrix); // This line of code gives me an error
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that arrays decays to pointers when you pass them to a function. So an array of arrays decays to a pointer to an array, with the type `sometype (*)[size]` where `size` is the size of your "inner" (second dimension) array.

However, the *exact* size have to be known at *compilation time* when you define or declare your function. If the size is unknown you simply can't do it. There is a workaround using templates though:

```
template<std::size_t SZ>
void indtastMatrix(double (*A)[SZ]);
```

---

Also note that [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) is a non-standard extension in some compilers. Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.